# Can the same php query handle simultaneous ajax requests from different pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a PHP page named u`pdate_details.php?id=xyz` which has a query for getting the details and updating the login time of the users.

The users have a profile page named `profile.php?id=xyz`. So for different users the profile page is different like `profile.php?id=abc`,   `profile.php?id=def` etc. Now this `profile.php` has an ajax function that sends the user id to the `update_details.php` through ajax call so that the `update_details.php` can update the record.

Now for example if I have 2000 users and all of them open their profile page simultaneously. Now my question is will the `update_details` page be able to handle this. I mean is it one `update_details.php` or each `update_details.php?id=abc`, `update_details.php?id=def` etc is considered to be a seperate one.

To be more precise, when 2000 users are updating their record through 2000 ajax calls, are the calls going to one `update_details.php` or to the one according to their ids like `update_details.php?id=abc`, `update_details.php?id=def` etc. TIA

Comment: One page for all users. Your question makes no sense. The Ajax req is made client side. The server will serve each call one after the other.

Comment: What Lelio said, this makes no sense, AJAX is made client side. Also you only have one profile.php not 2000, what you have is 2000 users who request the same profile.php, so asking if that your profile can handle 2000 request depends on your server not the script.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's check how the request goes from the browser till it's served and the browser gets a response.

1. The client clicks on a link, maybe a button.
2. The browser makes a HTTP request and sends it to the server ( that maybe Apache, nginx, whatever you use )
3. The server analyzes the request, checks its rules.. Saying : I found a rule when I hit a url with `.php` extension, I run a php interpreter and pass it the request info..
4. The server spawns new process or assign the request to one of its workers ( depends on the internals of the server ).

How many concurrent php processes will run ?  it depends on the web server configuration and design.

---

So to answer your question, each php process is running has its isolated memory segment even if they are executing the same instructions from `update_details.php`

Think of it like 10 workers in a factory crafting a chair following the same instruction, but each one uses a different paint color, wood type, etc..

Comment: Thanks. That answers my question. I was actually confused if it is one worker handling 2000 user requests since the query is in the same page or multiple workers.